# Are the available US National debt numbers gross or netted?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, government-debt

For instance, we know that Japan holds a large part of the foreign US debt, and at the same time, the US holds a foreign debt to Japan. My question is are the debt numbers of the US (for example, the total 31 trillion USD netted or not and is there are sources available where we can see the net debt of countries?

Comment: there are various measures of national debt. Could you please cite some specific number with a source?

Comment: I believe that this is a very common one: https://www.usdebtclock.org/